# How to make two corners round using RoundedBitmapDrawable in android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I have a progressbar and I used RoundedBitmapDrawable to pass a drawable as background, but how can I make **only** two corners round? If I use a xml as background I get no background.

```
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.progressbar);

RoundedBitmapDrawable dr = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), src);

dr.setCornerRadius(Math.max(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()) / 2.0f);
```

Comment: no, you have write your own `Drawable` based on `RoundedBitmapDrawable` code

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html  there is no such a utility provided

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this:

1. Copy `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable` and `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory` to your project, with different names (don't forget to change the package name and fix all imports/etc)
2. Edit the `public void draw(Canvas canvas)` method by replacing the `drawRoundRect` method call (line 264) with one of the solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896234/how-to-use-android-canvas-to-draw-a-rectangle-with-only-topleft-and-topright-cor).
3. Use your new class!

Tried adapting [Durza007's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5896484/2596742), which is the easiest, however it didn't work for me.

I ended up using [Mohammad Mahtabi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35668889/2596742): added his `public static Path RoundedRect()` to my `CustomRoundedBitmapDrawable` class, and replaced `drawRoundRect` with

```
Path path = RoundedRect(0, 0, mDstRect.width() , mDstRect.height(),  
    mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, true, true, false, false);
canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

Here, `true, true, false, false` means that the top left and right corners are rounded. It would be wise to make these parameters configurable in `HalfRoundedBitmapDrawable` to reuse the class later on.

Tested myself on 4.4 (KitKat), works like a charm.