# How to put the android BottomAppBar with rounded corners

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar

I am using the `BottomAppBar` from google like this:

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/vNavigationBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

The custom bottom bar is flat and I need to add rounded corners on the Bottom bar(image example bellow)

[image: Bottom bar example]

What should I do to make this work this way?

Comment: I strongly recommend not doing what you have in mind, since it goes against the Material Design Guidelines: https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#

Answer (score 14):

The BottomAppBar works with a **`MaterialShapeDrawable`** and you can apply to it rounded corners (using a `RoundedCornerTreatment`).

In your layout:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
      android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:backgroundTint="@color/..."
      ../>
```

Then in the code define:

```
//Corner radius
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);
BottomAppBar bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_app_bar);

MaterialShapeDrawable bottomBarBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) bottomAppBar.getBackground();
bottomBarBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
       bottomBarBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .build());
```

[image]

It works also with a `fabCradle`:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="8dp"
    app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
    .../>
```

[image]

It requires the version **1.1.0**.

Comment: not working  `val shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()  .toBuilder() 
 .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 16f)  
            .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 16f)  
            .build()  
  
        ViewCompat.setBackground(bottom_appbar, MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel))`

Comment: @AkshayRaj. Your code **works**, just tried. But `16f != 16dp`.

Comment: @AkshayRaj. I've updated the answer. The `BottomAppBar` provides a `MaterialShapeDrawable`. It is enough to apply the rounded corners to it changing the `ShapeAppearanceModel`

Comment: This is correct answer if you are targeting `Android L`

Answer (score 5):

you can try add a shape drawable xml file and add the following code to it

```
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:topRightRadius="16dp" />
```

And then set the BottomAppBar's background to the drawable

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35668889/4646999), you can create your customView class extended from BottomAppBar, and implement these code:

```
`@Override protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int 
 right, int bottom) {
 super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
 }
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
    mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mPath.reset();
    mPath = RoundedRect(0, 0, mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight, 50, 50, true);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

`

remember just in every constructor of your custom class,do this:

```
mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```