# Android : Add rounded corners to BottomAppBar with circular anchored FAB

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, custom-view, android-bottomnav, android-bottomappbar

I want to achieve something similar to this view, bottom navigation with top left and right rounded corner radius and a and anchored FAB [image]

Comment: For the BottomAppBar with rounded corners check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056217/2016562).

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, Thanks for your answer, I can achieve the top left and right corner radii alone, I also can achieve the anchored button, but I can not combine the 2 together because they are opposite to each other.

Comment: Why are they opposite to each other? can you post the code?

Comment: The idea is that if you want corner radius you can add custom shape with top right and left corner radii to the bottom navigation view component and if you added this to the app bottom bar component, it will hide the margin of the app bar component which is used to draw the anchor of the fab button, so i can have one of the 2 options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a standard `BottomAppBar`:

```
   <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:layout_margin="xxdp"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="8dp"
        app:fabCradleMargin="8dp" />
```

and then change the `ShapeAppearanceModel`:

```
    BottomAppBar bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar);
    MaterialShapeDrawable bottomBarBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) bottomAppBar.getBackground();
    bottomBarBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
            bottomBarBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                    .toBuilder()
                    .setAllCorners(new RoundedCornerTreatment()).setAllCornerSizes(new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f))
                    .build());
```

[image]

Just a note about new `RelativeCornerSize(0.5f)`: It changed in `1.2.0-beta01`. Before it was `new RelativeCornerSize(50)`

Comment: Thanka, Will try your solution