# How to create Path with rounded corners using rQuadTo that is equivalent to a specific dp?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, math, graphics

As background, I am new to Android graphics. I'm trying to create a rectangle with rounded corners using [Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) specifically (I don't want to use method `addRoundRect` as I will make changes to my `Path` object later to not be rectangular). I want this to have the same curvature as a [shape](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource) with corners with a radius of 12 dp. I'd like to use the methods [rQuadTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path#rQuadTo(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) or [quadTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path#quadTo(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) (based off of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896234/how-to-use-android-canvas-to-draw-a-rectangle-with-only-topleft-and-topright-cor)), but am a bit confused how to get the corners to match each other perfectly. Can someone explain the math behind how to to achieve this and what setting the radius exactly mean for drawable resource shape (is [this](http://roystonglass.co.uk/knowledgebase/q-what-is-a-radius-corner/) a correct definition?)? Visuals would be help as well! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, link contains correct definition.

To build rounded corner with quadratic Bezier `quadTo`, you should start curve (end straight line) at distance `r=12` before corner position, make control point exactly at corner position (to provide symmetry) and make end point at distance `r` after corner at perpendicular edge. Quadratic Bezier curve does not give perfect circle arc, but it is not significant for small sizes.

Example:
Horizontal edge in right direction to corner `100, 100`.
End point of line is `88, 100`. (and starting point of curve)
And `quadto(100, 100, 100, 112)`