# Rectangular bitmap to one side rounded rectangle

Tags: android, bitmap

I am looking to convert rectangular bitmap to one side rounded rectangle. For reference, you can see the door of the garage in the below pic

[image]

I want to transform a rectangular bitmap into this kind of shape. I know this is not too informative but I am new to this area and don't know what details to provide except this.

Comment: I can do it, but it has lot of codes

Comment: @Style-7 can you suggest idea and provide some links to learn those stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896234/how-to-use-android-canvas-to-draw-a-rectangle-with-only-topleft-and-topright-cor)

You have to create a new canvas with your bitmap, then you can shape it.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Picture);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

//shape your canvas as in the link described

//e.g. set the bitmap to a ImageView
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```